# Kotlin generic object sort: how would I sort by an object list parameters count or size

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a nifty generic function for a Kotlin js project that will sort a List of objects by parameter.

For instance, a list of book objects look like

```
data class Book(val id: Int, val title: String, val year: Int, val authors:List<Author>)
```

will be sorted by my generic function:

```
fun <T> sortColumnData(data: List<T>, direction: SORTDIRECTION, selector: KProperty1<T, Comparable<*>>) :List<T> {
    val sortedData = when (direction) {
        SORTDIRECTION.UP -> data.sortedWith(compareBy(selector))
        SORTDIRECTION.DOWN -> data.sortedWith(compareByDescending(selector))
    }
    return sortedData
}
```

And, I can pass the selector in very conveniently : Book::title

I need some direction in how to write a sortColumnData function that will sort by author count.

Comment: You are sorting by a property, Book.authors.size is not a property so for that you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: use lambda for your `selector` as `compareBy` does

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel, see the Kotlin standard library [Ordering|Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-ordering.html)

```
data class Author(val name: String)
data class Book(val id: Int, val title: String, val year: Int, val authors: List<Author>)

val authorA = Author("A")
val authorB = Author("B")

val list = listOf(
    Book(1, "Book 1", 2000, listOf(authorA)),
    Book(2, "Book 2", 2000, listOf(authorA)),
    Book(3, "Book 3", 2000, listOf(authorA, authorB)),
    Book(4, "Book 4", 2000, listOf(authorB))
)

list.sortedBy { it.title }.forEach(::println)
list.sortedByDescending { it.title }.forEach(::println)

list.sortedBy { it.authors.size }.forEach(::println)
list.sortedByDescending { it.authors.size }.forEach(::println)
```

You can also use Method Referencing:

```
val result = list.sortedBy(Book::title)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
val result = list.sortedBy { it.title }
```

For *list.sortedBy { it.authors.size }* it is not possible to use Method Reference.

––––––––––––––––––––

Edit:

You can add comparator functions to your data class, one for each comparison you want to do. You then add a second *sortColumnData* function with a *KFunction2* argument instead of a *KProperty1* one.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction2

data class Author(val name: String)

data class Book(val id: Int, val title: String, val year: Int, val authors: List<Author>): Comparable<Book> {
  override fun compareTo(other: Book) = compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.id }, { it.id })
  fun compareByAuthorCount(other: Book) = compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.authors.size }, { it.authors.size })
  fun compareByTitleLength(other: Book) = compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.title.length }, { it.title.length })
}

val authorA = Author("A")
val authorB = Author("B")

val list = listOf(
    Book(1, "Book 1 - 123", 2000, listOf(authorA)),
    Book(2, "Book 2 - 1", 2000, listOf(authorA)),
    Book(3, "Book 3 - 12", 2000, listOf(authorA, authorB)),
    Book(4, "Book 4 - ", 2000, listOf(authorB))
)

enum class SortDirection { UP, DOWN }

fun <T : Comparable<T>> sortColumnData(data: List<T>, direction: SortDirection, comparator: KFunction2<T, T, Int>): List<T> {
  return when (direction) {
    SortDirection.UP   -> data.sortedWith(comparator)
    SortDirection.DOWN -> data.sortedWith(comparator).reversed()
  }
}

sortColumnData(list, SortDirection.DOWN, Book::compareTo).forEach(::println)
// Ids: 4, 3, 2, 1

sortColumnData(list, SortDirection.UP, Book::compareByAuthorCount).forEach(::println)
// Ids: 1, 2, 4, 3 (UP = from least to most authors)

sortColumnData(list, SortDirection.UP, Book::compareByTitleLength).forEach(::println)
// Ids: 4, 2, 3, 1 (UP = from shortest to longest title)
```

Comment: it has to be generic though :(

i am trying to build out a data table widget

Comment: Very cool edit, i will try that ty